# How to cast a object with wildcards?

Tags: java, generics

How to cast a type with wildcards?
I tried with force type Conversion and cast. It could not work.
Here is type definition:

```
// type definition:
class Resource {
    xxxx
}

abstract class ResourceWrapper<T> {
    abstract T getData();
}

class Apple extends Resource {
    xxxx
}

class AppleWrapper extends ResourceWrapper<Apple> {
    private Apple apple;

    @Override
    public Apple getData() {
        return apple;
    }
}

enum ResourceTye {
    APPLE("apple", AppleWrapper.class);
    private String type;
    private Class<? extends ResourceWraper<? extends Resource>> clazz;
    
    public Class<? extends ResourceWraper<? extends Resource>> getWrapperClass() {
        return clazz;
    }
}

// method:
<T> T getResource(String type, Class<T> resourceType);

// caller:
client.getResource("test", AppleWrapper.class)
```

I need to mock `getResource` method.
Mock method like this:

```
    AppleWrapper appleWrapper = mock(AppleWrapper .class);
    when(client.getResource("test", resourceType.getWrapperClass))
        .thenReturn(appleWrapper);    // compile error
```

How to cast appleWrapper to warpper with wildcards?
Thank you.

Comment: You could use (ResourceWrapper<Apple>) to cast. I believe the correct term is "generics" instead of "wildcards".

Comment: Your enum is incomplete. What does `getWrapperClass()` return? It should return `AppleWrapper.class` to match your call.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC compile error as mockito thenReturn is also a generic method

Comment: I use ```when(xxx).thenAnswer(invocation -> appleWrapper)``` to skip this cast, and it works.